# How can I log button press events using IOHIDEvent on iOS?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, iokit

I tried this in iOS, but it would segfault, and outputs nothing in a ramdisk: https://iphonedev.wiki/index.php/IOHIDFamily

I know ramrod in a OTA update uses IOHID, I looked inside it and when you press a button during a update it says "iPhone will restart when update completes"

Does anyone know how to log button events on iOS?